# Is it possible to parallelize bz2's decompression?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, bzip2, bzip

I am using pythons [bz2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html) module to generate (and compress) a large jsonl file (bzip2 compressed 17GB).

However, when I later try to decompress it using pbzip2 it only seems to use *one* CPU-core for decompression, which is quite slow.

When i compress it with pbzip2 it can leverage multiple cores on decompression. Is there a way to compress within python in the pbzip2-compatible format?

```
import bz2,sys
from Queue import Empty
#...
compressor = bz2.BZ2Compressor(9)
f = open(path, 'a')

    try:
        while 1:
            m = queue.get(True, 1*60)
            f.write(compressor.compress(m+"\n"))
    except Empty, e:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        sys.stderr.write("flushing")
        f.write(compressor.flush())
        f.close()
```

Comment: From what I've read parallelizing disk I/O is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993707/3727854). That being said [this answer may be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42012661/3727854)  to this question.

Comment: @JamesDraper disk I/O won't be the limiting factor though ... bzip computations are slow

Comment: @worenga Note that jsonl is a dangerous format if you might ever use top-level numbers, since they are prone to truncation. Json-seq fixes that problem by mandating an error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `BZ2Compressor` rather than `BZ2File`?

Comment: @o11c BZ2File does not support mode 'a'.

Comment: @worenga Ooh, didn't realize you were stuck on python2. Still, when you pass an existing file object, that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `pbzip2` stream is nothing more than the concatenation of multiple `bzip2` streams.

An example using the shell:

```bash
bzip2 < /usr/share/dict/words > words_x_1.bz2
cat words_x_1.bz2{,,,,,,,,,} > words_x_10.bz2
time bzip2 -d < words_x_10.bz2 > /dev/null
time pbzip2 -d < words_x_10.bz2 > /dev/null
```

I've never used python's `bz2` module, but it should be easy to close/reopen a stream in `'a'`ppend mode, every so-many bytes, to get the same result. Note that if `BZ2File` is constructed from an existing file-like object, closing the `BZ2File` will not close the underlying stream (which is what you want here).

I haven't measured how many bytes is optimal for chunking, but I would guess every 1-20 megabytes - it definitely needs to be larger than the bzip2 block size (900k) though.

Note also that if you record the compressed and uncompressed offsets of each chunk, you can do fairly efficient random access. This is how the `dictzip` program works, though that is based on `gzip`.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must use `pbzip2` on decompression this won't help you, but the alternative `lbzip2` can perform multicore decompression of "normal" `.bz2` files, such as those generated by Python's `BZ2File` or a traditional `bzip2` command. This avoids the limitation of `pbzip2` you're describing, where it can only achieve parallel decompression if the file is also compressed using `pbzip2`. See https://github.com/kjn/lbzip2/.

As a bonus, benchmarks suggest `lbzip2` is substantially faster than `pbzip2`, both on decompression (by 30%) and compression (by 40%) while achieving slightly superior compression ratios. Further, its peak RAM usage is less than 50% of the RAM used by `pbzip2`. See https://vbtechsupport.com/1614/.